# Can you replicate a password input with a text input?

Tags: css, input, passwords

In other words, are the following equivalent?

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" />

<style>
   input[type="text"] {
     -webkit-text-security: disc;
     text-security: disc;
   }
</style>
```

and

```
<input type="password" />
```

Comment: I'm inclined to say yes, but why would you want to do this? A password input is just a text field with those properties already set?

Comment: There is no way to override the text-security discs/bullets/dots with input[type="password"]

Comment: But why? Are you looking to switch it as a "Show password" option or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

No they are not

`<input type="password" />` is compatible on all browsers of all versions, while the other is not.

But technically the output result is the same on modern browsers that support even one css property of it.